# setup.py to include a Git repository (with optional dependencies) as a dependency

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have two Python packages hosted on - `pkg-a` and `pkg-b`.

`pkg-a` has optional dependencies that I am able to install with:

```py
pip install git+https://github.com/username/pkg-a.git@v0.1.0#egg=pkg-a[all]
```

The problem is that `pkg-b` depends on `pkg-a` (along with all the optional dependencies). However, the following line in `pkg-b`'s `setup.py` does not install the optional dependencies.

```py
INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    'pkg-a @ git+https://github.com/username/pkg-a.git@v0.1.0#egg=pkg-a[all]'
]
```

It only installs the **required** dependencies of `pkg-a`. What am I missing here? How do I specify that all of `pkg-a`'s **optional** dependencies should be installed when installing `pkg-b`?

Comment: I think you’re saying those other packages are not optional if you’re installing B and therefore B should state them as dependencies.

Comment: So you are saying in addition to A, I should explicitly specify the other packages as dependencies as well?

Comment: Well if B cannot run without them then B needs to state them as dependencies. It cannot rely on A bringing them in because A doesn’t care if they’re there or not.

Comment: interesting, thank you